# Conditions on regex 1 to 8 characters not working

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match string which,

1. should contain at least one character which is not a space
2. the string should be 1 to 8 characters in length,

I wonder why the below code is not working when i want to restrict to 1 to 8 characters.

```
.*\S.{1,8}
```

should match,

```
abcdefge

 abcdefg   - first character is space, Any number of spaces can be there, but atleaset one non space character should be there

       a
```

Should not match,

```
            - All spaces
 abcdefghijklm - Exeeds more then 8 characters
```

Thanks

Comment: This is nowhere nearly the right expression. It requires one to eight chars preceded by a non-whitespace char, preceded by any number of chars. The total length this can match ranges from 2 to infinity.

Comment: so, what corrections i had to make?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the text you want to parse and what should be the result.

Comment: Edited the question and added the sameples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a look-ahead for your first criteria, and a quantified 'anything' character combined with start and end anchors for the second:

```
/^(?=.*\S).{1,8}$/
```

(this isn't tested so my apologies for the bugs)

Comment: I works fine, but if the first character is space, it is not matching

Comment: FirmView, you may be testing the regex before sweaver2112's edit. This one seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The non-regex expression is quite simple and straightforward:

```
s.length() <= 8 && s.trim().length() > 0
```

Comment: What about using trim() first?

Comment: @Luciano Well, what about it? I don't get your question. Are you suggesting to first trim and then test?

Comment: Yes, if all characters are spaces, after trim the string length would be 0.

Comment: @Luciano And why is that a good thing? Do you suggest writing the second test with an alternative approach? I could just write `return s.trim().length() > 0`.

Comment: I was only thinking of using an existing method of String instead of looping. So the test would only be s.length() <= 8 && s.trim().length() > 0

Comment: @Luciano My original looping version was sligthly faster since `trim` does more work than necessary, but in real life I would opt for simpler code. I have updated to use `trim`, but haven't taken it to full extent. Your version is the shortest, but also the slowest since it doesn't eliminate empty string at the outset. However, I like its simplicity and would probably write it like that in real life.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I think there is a better alternative to do this.

**2.** First check for the String to be of **length between 1 and 8,**

**3.** If Yes then, use `!Characters.isWhitespace()` method to check that its a **non-space character.**

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
str.matches("(?=.*[^ ]).{1,8}")
```